# Android change button colors only

Tags: android, android-styles

For my android project I have some default buttons.
To make the app look nicer I try to change the colors with the following code :

```
<style name="CustomStyle"parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">       
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
</style>  

<style name="CustomButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/buttonBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonTextColor</item>
</style>
```

The color of the buttons are adjusted like I want but all the exisiting default heights and paddings are gone.

How should I adjust the colors of my button **without losing the existing padding and height and other default values**?

I want to change the style for all buttons in my app in multiple fragments/activitys so doing it programmaticly is not prefered.

Minimum api level that I use is 14, if I used api level 21 or higher I could use backgroundTint instead of background and get the right result but this is not an option now.

Comment: Try using a xml selector in your drawable and create a style using that drawable and use the style across your views.

Answer (score 0):

Android default button uses a 9 patch drawable as background.

[image]

which has some default padding, look at the content area defined by the right and bottom lines.

You can define padding as well in the custom style you have.

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/buttonBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/custom_button_padding</item>
</style>
```

Comment: tried it in a relative layour with buttons but there is no spacing also tried using layout_margin instead also didnt work. if i add layout_margin 8dp in the button itself it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it programatically with :

```
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

or if you want to do it using styles:

1) You should insert a dimension value within the style xml:

```
<dimen name="buttonHeight">40px</dimen>
```

2) Reference the dimension value. So in your layout file you'll write:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
```

Comment: I want to change the style for all buttons in my app in multiple fragments/activitys so doing it programmaticly is not prefered.